# Docker Related Deployment Issue in Java Robotic Automation application

Tags: java, docker, maven, java-17

I am currently working on a Robotic automation application based on Java 17, The build tool used in this application is Maven 3.9.2.

I have been successful in building this application in a local development environment. To do so the used command was

```
mvn clean install -Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties
```

This command is used to build and install a Maven project with specific profiles and configuration properties. In summary, the command is cleaning the project, compiling and packaging it, and then installing it in the local Maven repository. It's also activating the "dev" profile and specifying a configuration file named "config-dev.properties" for use during the build. The specifics of the "dev" profile and "config-dev.properties" are listed below.

Special parameters were used in the maven command to handle special scenarios related to the project at hand.

**-Pdev:** This activates the Maven profile named "dev". Maven profiles allow you to customize the build process for different environments or scenarios. In this case, the "dev" profile is being activated.

**-DactiveProfile=dev:** This sets a system property named "activeProfile" with the value "dev". This can be used within the Maven build to conditionally execute certain tasks based on the active profile.

**-DconfigFile=config-dev.properties:** This sets a system property named "configFile" with the value "config-dev.properties". Similar to the "activeProfile" property, this allows configuration parameters to be passed to the Maven build. In this case, it specifies a configuration file to be used during the build.

For multiple environments, I have maintained multiple config files with development environment-specific information.
Config-dev.properties,config_localqa.properties, config_clientqa.properties, etc.

Configuration.xlsm with rapport preferences is also available which the selenium application uses as a reference. these files are in the resource folder.

**Related POM.xml contents**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>report-automation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <!-- Default config file for fallback -->
    <config.file>config.properties</config.file>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version> <!-- Use your specific version -->
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Model.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>Configuration.xlsm</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <!-- Profile for Development Environment -->
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <config.file>config-dev.properties</config.file>
        <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Profile for Local QA Environment -->
    <profile>
      <id>localqa</id>
      <properties>
        <config.file>config-localqa.properties</config.file>
        <activeProfile>localqa</activeProfile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Add profiles for other environments -->
    <!--
        <profile>
            <id>clientuat</id>
            <properties>
                <config.file>config-clientuat.properties</config.file>
                <activeProfile>clientuat</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>clientqa</id>
            <properties>
                <config.file>config-clientqa.properties</config.file>
                <activeProfile>clientqa</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <config.file>config-production.properties</config.file>
                <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        -->
  </profiles>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TestNG -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ExtentReports -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OpenCSV -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache POI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- maven-invoker -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.22</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Config-dev.properties contents**

```
Backup-File Location
relativeDownloadLocation = Downloads/

File-Location for Back-End Service
absoluteDownloadLocation = ../backend-service/src/main/resources/report/

configFilePath
configFilePath = src/main/resources/config-dev.properties

Project Directory
project.directory=.

Project Resource Directory
resource.directory=src/main/resources/

Maven Home - change according to environment
maven.home=/rezsystem/apache-maven-3.9.2

Availability Report properties
availabilityReportFileName=Availability Report.csv

comprehensive report properties
comprehensiveReportFileName=Comprehensive Sales Report Detailed.csv
```

My Issue is when I attempt to Dockerize this application I am facing a few issues.
I attempted to update the Docker file to handle the local development scenario.

**Docker File**

```
# Use the official Maven image as a build stage
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17 AS builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the Maven project and create the JAR file
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties"
RUN mvn clean install $MAVEN_OPTS

# Use the official OpenJDK 17 image as the final image
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the JAR file from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/report-automation.jar /app/report-automation.jar

# Copy the appropriate config file based on Maven profile
COPY src/main/resources/config-dev.properties /app/src/main/resources/config-dev.properties

# Copy the Configuration.xlsm file from the source to the working directory in the container
COPY src/main/resources/Configuration.xlsm /app/src/main/resources/Configuration.xlsm

# Expose the port (if your application listens on a specific port)
# EXPOSE 8080

# Set the entry point for the container (replace with your main class)
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "report-automation.jar"]
```

**Docker build command used**
docker build --build-arg MAVEN_OPTS="-Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties" -t selenium-app  .

**Encountered Error**

```
docker build --build-arg MAVEN_OPTS="-Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties" -t selenium-app .
[+] Building 3.7s (10/14)                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.19kB                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17                                                                                                           2.6s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8-openjdk-17                                                                                                 2.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 33.52kB                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8-openjdk-17@sha256:3a9c30b3af6278a8ae0007d3a3bf00fff80ec3ed7ae4eb9bfa1772853101549b                                   0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17@sha256:528707081fdb9562eb819128a9f85ae7fe000e2fbaeaf9f87662e7b3f38cb7d8                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [builder 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                              0.6s
 => ERROR [builder 4/4] RUN mvn clean install -Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties                                                              0.4s
------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN mvn clean install -Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties:
#0 0.291 Unrecognized option: -Pdev
#0 0.291 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
#0 0.291 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn clean install $MAVEN_OPTS]: exit code: 1
```

How can I resolve these issues encountered when attempting to Dockerize the application? Are there any updates required in the Docker file?

Comment: In another forum where this issue was discussed, it was proposed that the problem might be caused by an invisible, invalid character on the screen. Maven 3.8 offers the -Pdev option and should also function within a container, so the only conceivable issue could be related to characters. Occasionally, for instance, the hyphen "-" might be replaced with a similar-looking character when copied from a different source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses. I checked it locally and this command works but in the container, it seems to fail. Checked the special character scenario also but I couldn’t verify any such characters.

I also tried out the above-mentioned solution but unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Nevertheless, I refactored the code and removed the dependency for the **-Pdev** option. Once I did this the existing error was resolved.

**New commands used in refactored code**

**mvn clean install -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties**

**docker build --build-arg MAVEN_OPTS=“-DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties” -t selenium-app .**

Updated the above-mentioned Docker file with this change

**Build the Maven project and create the JAR file**
*ARG MAVEN_OPTS=“-DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties”
RUN mvn clean install $MAVEN_OPTS*

Answer (score 2):

You can switch from [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form) to [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form) to make this work:

```
# Use the official Maven image as a build stage
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17 AS builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the Maven project and create the JAR file
ARG MAVEN_OPTS="-Pdev -DactiveProfile=dev -DconfigFile=config-dev.properties"
CMD ["mvn", "clean", "install", MAVEN_OPTS]
```